# Render Macro control on page load in umbraco template

Tags: asp.net, razor, macros, umbraco, pageload

I am trying to load the razor script which exists as a separate macro in umbraco. I am using umbraco 4.7.0

I am basically doing geo-targeting and hence need to run the script each time on a page load. so I am looking for something like :

```
 <script type="c#" runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Call the Macro here
  }
```

Obviously I can do this in the template

```
 <umbraco:Macro Alias="GeoTargetting" runat="server" />
```

but I need to call this macro before any control is loaded in the page.

PLease help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please tell what is the exact need to do this.. Whether to run any code in the macro page load?

Comment: @mahesh : Thanks for it. The basic need is to avoid caching and load the macro content based on the url. What happens is, if I change the url of the page, it loads the page but the macro is cached due to which I am not able to get the exact contents in the macro.

I have few conditions in the macro which needs to be invoked even if it's a postback.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by "macro is cached due to which I am not able to get the exact contents in the macro". If you want to do things in all request you can use an **httpHandler** which will override all the page life cycle events. So all the page events will be routed through this handler events.

Comment: @aneesh, why don't you just disable caching on the macro?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work alright:

**Template:**

```
<umbraco:Macro Alias="Sandbox" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="Yo"></asp:Label>
```

**Macro Script:**

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@inherits DynamicNodeContext
@{
    Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
    page.Load += new EventHandler(page_Load);
}

@functions
{
    static void page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page page = sender as Page;
        Label label = FindControlRecursive(page, "Label1") as Label;
        label.Text = "Hello";
    }

    private static Control FindControlRecursive(Control Root, string Id)
    {
        if (Root.ID == Id)
            return Root;

        foreach (Control Ctl in Root.Controls)
        {
            Control FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(Ctl, Id);

            if (FoundCtl != null)
                return FoundCtl;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Note:** The `FindControlRecursive()` method is from this [forum thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1107107.aspx/1).